# Pycrypto AES-CTR implementation

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

I am new to python and pycrypto.
I am trying to implement AES-CTR. To check my program for correct ciphering I tried to use test sequences from NIST SP 800-38A standard (section F.5). But I do not get correct result. What am I doing wrong?

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Utils import Counter

CTRkey="2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c"
ctr=Counter.new(128, initial_value=int("f0f1f2f3f4f5f6f7f8f9fafbfcfdfeff",16))
cipherCTR=AES.new(CTRkey, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
print(cipherCTR.encrypt("f0f1f2f3f4f5f6f7f8f9fafbfcfdfeff".decode("hex")).encode("hex"))
```

Result:

```
0008007df81ad564b9aadd6b883fef16
```

But the expected result (*ciphertext*) is:

```
874d6191b620e3261bef6864990db6ce
```

Comment: Welcome Re-pythonable. Don't forget to add at least one of the [tag:cryptography] and [tag:encryption] tags to your cryptography related question or it won't show up on many radars :)

Comment: I don't know if `Crypto.Utils` had this name earlier or it's a type because what I am able to import is `Crypto.Util`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the NIST SP 800-38A standard (section F.5.1), the input to the CTR-AES128 encryption operation is called *plaintext* not *input block*.

If you use the *plaintext* (`6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a`) you get the correct result, the *ciphertext* `874d6191b620e3261bef6864990db6ce`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this.

```
import Crypto.Cipher.AES
import Crypto.Util.Counter

import binascii

key = b'\x2b\x7e\x15\x16\x28\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\x09\xcf\x4f\x3c'
iv = b'\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
text = b'\x6b\xc1\xbe\xe2\x2e\x40\x9f\x96\xe9\x3d\x7e\x11\x73\x93\x17\x2a'

ctr = Crypto.Util.Counter.new(128, initial_value=int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16))
cipher = Crypto.Cipher.AES.new(key, Crypto.Cipher.AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
print(cipher.encrypt(text).encode("hex"))
```

got result

```
874d6191b620e3261bef6864990db6ce
```

use binary data work for me, and str.encode("hex") is not recommended

Comment: Hi, you could improve you answer by explaining how your solution solves the original poster's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using the appropriate plain text value as mention by SquareRootOfTwentyThree, you should also consider the type of data being used in the code.  The [PyCrypto documentation](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#ctr-mode) suggests that the data type of keys to be *bytes*, whereas the counter can be of type *int* or *bytes*.

You will need to use appropriate datatype to get the cipher text mentioned in NIST SP 800-38A. Kameel's code works, I have included the code in my answer as well.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import Crypto.Utils.Counter
import binascii

CTRkey     = b'\x2b\x7e\x15\x16\x28\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\x09\xcf\x4f\x3c'
iv         = b'\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
plain_text = b'\x6b\xc1\xbe\xe2\x2e\x40\x9f\x96\xe9\x3d\x7e\x11\x73\x93\x17\x2a'

ctr       = Crypto.UtilsCounter.new(128, initial_value=int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16))
cipherCTR = AES.new(CTRkey, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
print(cipherCTR.encrypt(plain_text).encode("hex"))
```

Comment: It'd be awesome if you added a code snippet with an example.